# The cell of jupyter notebook is not running. FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

Hi my name is Sahil Imran and I am stuck in a problem in jupyter-notebook

DATA ANALYSIS:

```
df=pandas.read_csv("C:\\out\\supermarkets.xlsx")
df
```

I don't know why it says `FileNotFoundError`.
I actually put this file in (C:).
I wanted to solved this for a long time.

I copied it from "The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Application Udemy"

Can you solve this problem?

Comment: There is so much you can do prior to asking stack overflow why a program you wrote cannot find a file you think is in the correct location **on your computer** or **in your environment**. For example, you can try using [os.listdir](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm) to see if you code actually sees the file there.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to keep the dataset in the same directory as that of your notebook , no need to include path in that case just include the name in inverted commas.